# Realm migration issue on update application

Tags: android, realm

I did some `migration` `realm` testing on Android Studio emulators and got no problems, but in `production` some devices are having `trouble` migrating.

In version 1:

```
public class Configuration extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Realm.init(this);

        RealmConfiguration configuration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
                .name("myapp.realm").schemaVersion(1).build();
        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(configuration);
    }
}
```

In version 2:

```
public class Configuration extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Realm.init(this);
        RealmConfiguration configuration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
                .name("myapp.realm").schemaVersion(2).migration(new MyMigration()).build();
        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(configuration);

    }

    private class MyMigration implements RealmMigration {
        @Override
        public void migrate(DynamicRealm realm, long oldVersion, long newVersion) {
            RealmSchema schema = realm.getSchema();

            if (oldVersion == 1) {
                schema.get(ClassRealm.class.getSimpleName())
                        .addField(ClassRealm.STRING_FIELD_NAME, String.class);

                schema.create(AnotherClassRealm.class.getSimpleName())
                        .addField(AnotherClassRealm.INTEGER_FIELD_NAME, Integer.class, FieldAttribute.PRIMARY_KEY)
                        .addField(AnotherClassRealm.STRING_FIELD1_NAME, String.class, FieldAttribute.REQUIRED)
                        .addField(AnotherClassRealm.STRING_FIELD2_NAME, String.class, FieldAttribute.REQUIRED)
                        .addField(AnotherClassRealm.DATE_FIELD_NAME, Date.class, FieldAttribute.REQUIRED);
                oldVersion++;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

After upgrading to the new version the error:

Device: Galaxy J5 (j5lte),
Android: 6.0

```
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'io.realm.RealmObjectSchema io.realm.RealmObjectSchema.a(java.lang.String, java.lang.Class, io.realm.e[])' on a null object reference
    at myapp.configuration.Configuration$MyMigration.migrate(Configuration.java)
    at io.realm.BaseRealm$4.onResult(BaseRealm.java)
    at io.realm.RealmCache.createRealmOrGetFromCache(RealmCache.java)
    at <OR>.release(RealmCache.java)
    at <OR>.validateConfiguration(RealmCache.java)
    at <OR>.invokeWithGlobalRefCount(RealmCache.java)
    at <OR>.updateSchemaCache(RealmCache.java)
    at <OR>.findColumnIndices(RealmCache.java)
    at <OR>.storeColumnIndices(RealmCache.java)
    at io.realm.BaseRealm.isInTransaction(BaseRealm.java)
    at <OR>.setVersion(BaseRealm.java)
    at <OR>.get(BaseRealm.java)
    at <OR>.get(BaseRealm.java)
    at <OR>.get(BaseRealm.java)
    at <OR>.deleteRealm(BaseRealm.java)
    at <OR>.migrateRealm(BaseRealm.java)
    at io.realm.Realm.init(Realm.java)
    at <OR>.createInstance(Realm.java)
    at <OR>.initializeRealm(Realm.java)
    at <OR>.createObject(Realm.java)
    at <OR>.createObjectInternal(Realm.java)
    at <OR>.copyToRealm(Realm.java)
    at <OR>.copyFromRealm(Realm.java)
    at <OR>.where(Realm.java)
    at <OR>.executeTransaction(Realm.java)
    at <OR>.copyOrUpdate(Realm.java)
    at <OR>.createDetachedCopy(Realm.java)
    at <OR>.checkMaxDepth(Realm.java)
    at <OR>.migrateRealm(Realm.java)
    at <OR>.updateSchemaCache(Realm.java)
    at <OR>.isInTransaction(Realm.java)
    at io.realm.Realm.init(Realm.java)
    at <OR>.createInstance(Realm.java)
    at <OR>.initializeRealm(Realm.java)
    at <OR>.createObject(Realm.java)
    at <OR>.createObjectInternal(Realm.java)
    at <OR>.copyToRealm(Realm.java)
    at <OR>.copyFromRealm(Realm.java)
    at <OR>.where(Realm.java)
    at <OR>.executeTransaction(Realm.java)
    at <OR>.copyOrUpdate(Realm.java)
    at <OR>.createDetachedCopy(Realm.java)
    at <OR>.checkMaxDepth(Realm.java)
    at <OR>.migrateRealm(Realm.java)
    at <OR>.updateSchemaCache(Realm.java)
    at <OR>.isInTransaction(Realm.java)
    at io.realm.RealmCache.createRealmOrGetFromCache(RealmCache.java)
    at <OR>.release(RealmCache.java)
    at <OR>.validateConfiguration(RealmCache.java)
    at <OR>.invokeWithGlobalRefCount(RealmCache.java)
    at <OR>.updateSchemaCache(RealmCache.java)
    at <OR>.findColumnIndices(RealmCache.java)
    at <OR>.storeColumnIndices(RealmCache.java)
    at io.realm.Realm.getDefaultInstance(Realm.java)
    at myapp.MyView.onCreate(MyView.java)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3266)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Another:
Device: Galaxy S3 Neo (s3ve3gds), Android: 4.4

```
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2500)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:171)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1309)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5679)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at myapp.configuration.Configuration$MyMigration.migrate(Configuration.java)
    at io.realm.BaseRealm$4.onResult(BaseRealm.java)
    at io.realm.RealmCache.createRealmOrGetFromCache(RealmCache.java)
    at <OR>.release(RealmCache.java)
    at <OR>.validateConfiguration(RealmCache.java)
    at <OR>.invokeWithGlobalRefCount(RealmCache.java)
    at <OR>.updateSchemaCache(RealmCache.java)
    at <OR>.findColumnIndices(RealmCache.java)
    at <OR>.storeColumnIndices(RealmCache.java)
    at io.realm.BaseRealm.isInTransaction(BaseRealm.java)
    at <OR>.setVersion(BaseRealm.java)
    at <OR>.get(BaseRealm.java)
    at <OR>.get(BaseRealm.java)
    at <OR>.get(BaseRealm.java)
    at <OR>.deleteRealm(BaseRealm.java)
    at <OR>.migrateRealm(BaseRealm.java)
    at io.realm.Realm.init(Realm.java)
    at <OR>.createInstance(Realm.java)
    at <OR>.initializeRealm(Realm.java)
    at <OR>.createObject(Realm.java)
    at <OR>.createObjectInternal(Realm.java)
    at <OR>.copyToRealm(Realm.java)
    at <OR>.copyFromRealm(Realm.java)
    at <OR>.where(Realm.java)
    at <OR>.executeTransaction(Realm.java)
    at <OR>.copyOrUpdate(Realm.java)
    at <OR>.createDetachedCopy(Realm.java)
    at <OR>.checkMaxDepth(Realm.java)
    at <OR>.migrateRealm(Realm.java)
    at <OR>.updateSchemaCache(Realm.java)
    at <OR>.isInTransaction(Realm.java)
    at io.realm.Realm.init(Realm.java)
    at <OR>.createInstance(Realm.java)
    at <OR>.initializeRealm(Realm.java)
    at <OR>.createObject(Realm.java)
    at <OR>.createObjectInternal(Realm.java)
    at <OR>.copyToRealm(Realm.java)
    at <OR>.copyFromRealm(Realm.java)
    at <OR>.where(Realm.java)
    at <OR>.executeTransaction(Realm.java)
    at <OR>.copyOrUpdate(Realm.java)
    at <OR>.createDetachedCopy(Realm.java)
    at <OR>.checkMaxDepth(Realm.java)
    at <OR>.migrateRealm(Realm.java)
    at <OR>.updateSchemaCache(Realm.java)
    at <OR>.isInTransaction(Realm.java)
    at io.realm.RealmCache.createRealmOrGetFromCache(RealmCache.java)
    at <OR>.release(RealmCache.java)
    at <OR>.validateConfiguration(RealmCache.java)
    at <OR>.invokeWithGlobalRefCount(RealmCache.java)
    at <OR>.updateSchemaCache(RealmCache.java)
    at <OR>.findColumnIndices(RealmCache.java)
    at <OR>.storeColumnIndices(RealmCache.java)
    at io.realm.Realm.getDefaultInstance(Realm.java)
    at myapp.MyView.onCreate(MyView.java)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5582)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2405)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2500)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:171)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1309)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5679)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

All devices:

- Galaxy Grand Neo (baffinlitedtv)
- Galaxy Tab3V 7.0 (goyave3gsea)
- Galaxy S7 Edge (hero2lte)
- Galaxy J5(2016) (j5xnlte)
- Moto G(4) Plus (athene_f)
- Galaxy J1 Mini (j1mini3g)
- Galaxy Win2 (coreprimeltedtv)
- Lenovo K5 (A6020l36)
- Moto G Turbo Edition (merlin)
- Moto G4 Play (harpia_t)
- Galaxy S3 Neo (s3ve3gds)
- STUDIO_SELFIE
- Galaxy Core2 (kanas)
- Galaxy J2 (j2lte)
- Galaxy Grand Prime (fortuna3gdtv)
- Galaxy J3(2016) (j3xlte)

Comment: Could you please share the full stacktrace?

Comment: and the devices where migration fails?

Comment: I edited with the requested changes.

Comment: It seems `schema.get(ClassRealm.class.getSimpleName())` returns `null`. Was `ClassRealm` exist in schema v0 and v1? I assume `ClassRealm.class.getSimpleName()` should always return `"ClassRealm"`, but i am not quite sure if there are any exceptions on those devices?

Comment: have you ever released an apk with schema version 0?

Comment: Yes, the class exist in previous version. No, the first version started on 1. Fields are also called statically, will update.

Comment: How many versions of apk have been released? Do you mind to share all of them with us privately? to help@realm.io . thanks!

Comment: Three versions were released, I'll send, thank you.

Comment: See zaki's answer below. I tried your apks and i can reproduce it by install v2 first then update it to v3. It seems you started using proguard from v3, so that caused the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use ProGuard, model classes are obfuscated.
That means `ClassRealm.class.getSimpleName()` does not return `"ClassRealm"`.

It's an expected behavior.

Of course you can keep the names of model classes by adding your own proguard configuration.

Comment: That's right, it makes perfect sense, thank you all!

Answer (score -1):

You can just use a @keep annotation on the whole MyMigration class, if you don't care much about exposing the logic as the class would be left un-obfuscated by proguard.

```
import android.support.annotation.Keep

@Keep
private class MyMigration implements RealmMigration {
    @Override
    public void migrate(DynamicRealm realm, long oldVersion, long newVersion) {
        RealmSchema schema = realm.getSchema();

        if (oldVersion == 1) {
            schema.get(ClassRealm.class.getSimpleName())
                    .addField(ClassRealm.STRING_FIELD_NAME, String.class);

            schema.create(AnotherClassRealm.class.getSimpleName())
                    .addField(AnotherClassRealm.INTEGER_FIELD_NAME, Integer.class, FieldAttribute.PRIMARY_KEY)
                    .addField(AnotherClassRealm.STRING_FIELD1_NAME, String.class, FieldAttribute.REQUIRED)
                    .addField(AnotherClassRealm.STRING_FIELD2_NAME, String.class, FieldAttribute.REQUIRED)
                    .addField(AnotherClassRealm.DATE_FIELD_NAME, Date.class, FieldAttribute.REQUIRED);
            oldVersion++;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This didn't work for me, additionally `Keep` is no longer part of the android support libraries, I think the equivalent is in android x now